# Keepass password safe corrupt

Tags: windows-10, dropbox, keepass

I store all my passwords in a Keepass 2 `.kdbx` file. When I try to open it I get the error that "the file is corrupt". I had the file synced with dropbox. I thought this would be a good back up. I had added an entry to the file recently, then ran dropbox. I haven't run dropbox on the other computer yet.

It's funny, I thought syncing a file to the cloud is like a backup but I guess if one gets corrupt, now they all are. This is basically the worst thing that can happen.

Comment: If it still works on the other computer, copy the file from there to a few good places. To get the good copy into dropbox, try adding a small entry, make sure it still works, then let drop box sync it to the cloud.

Comment: KeePass 2.x Only In order to use the repair functionality in KeePass 2.x, first create a new database file. Then, go 'File' -> 'Import' and import the corrupted database file, using 'KeePass KDBX (2.x) (Repair Mode)' as format. Try that and see what happens. [Link to help documentation](http://keepass.info/help/base/repair.html)

Comment: At the very least you should be able to go to the Dropbox website and see the history for the file. From there you should be able to restore it to an earlier version.

Comment: @DrZoo I was able to repair it, though how can I know if any entries were lost? The important one's I remember are there.